# preg_match include forward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is the function I have that checks if the entered security question and/or answer contain malicious characters:

```
function validate_input($field) {
    $ErrorMessage = ""; 
    $field = preg_replace("/[\s]+is/", '', $field);
    if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9'?!-\s]+$/", $field ) ===0) {
        $ErrorMessage .= "<div class='error_message'>Potentially malicious characters found in:<i> " . $field . ",</i> please enter only alphanumeric characters</div/><br/>";
    } return $ErrorMessage;
}
```

When I enter something like "What's up?" for the question, it comes back with an error. When I do a var_dump on ($field) it comes back as "What\'s up?".

So how can I include the forward slash as an acceptable character?

Comment: Are you checking for "malicious characters" to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/). When you use prepared statements in either, they will help prevent sql injection, making your above code unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that you have the "magic quote" feature of PHP active, which shouldn't be for security reasons: all the escaping of user inserted data should be done by your own code.

Anyway, if you want to keep things as they are now, replace your

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9'?!-\s]+$/", $field)
```

with

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9'?!-\s\\\\]+$/", $field )
```

the quadruple \ is there because you need to escape it both, for being in a string delimited with double quotes and for being in a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Example that allows forward slash and other normal characters.

```
    $string = "Jâ€™s Bikes/IHOP";  // bad user input 
    if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%&()*;:_.'\/\\\\ ]+$/", $string)) {
       echo "Invalid $string";          
       }
```